# 'hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist con GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

He creado dos entidades, Autor y Libro con una relación OneToMany.
Ambas entidades tienen autogeneración de clave GenerationType.IDENTITY, 
y recibo siempre el mismo error.
Este error parece ocurrir con MariaDB pero no con MySQL.

```
ERROR: Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=820) Table 'pruebas2.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:242)
...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'pruebas2.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1594)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1453)
```

Las entidades serían así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Autor")
public class Autor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="idAutor")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idAutor;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Libro> libros = new ArrayList<Libro>();
...
}
```

Y la entidad Libro con relación inversa ManyToOne

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Libro")
public class Libro implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="idLibro")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idLibro;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAutor")
    private Autor autor;
...
}
```

Uso una AbstractJpaDAO genérica para implementar los métodos que necesitaré para realizar las operaciones

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaDAO<T extends Serializable> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

...
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?. Recibo este mensaje tanto si creo las tablas desde MariaDB a mano como si dejo que 
lo haga el JPA con "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create".

He leído esta "solución" que no funciona, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813666/table-dbname-hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist/49813851, 
y esta otra https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968527/hibernate-sequence-doesnt-exist
que dicen que cambiando GenerationType.AUTO a GenerationType.IDENTITY. Pero a mi me pasa con GenerationType.IDENTITY en ambas entidades.
¿Hay alguna forma de configurar la aplicación o la base de datos MariaDB para que no aparezcan estos errores?

Comment: ¿Tienen tus tablas secuencias creadas y asociadas a la columna id?

Answer (score 0):

yo defino de esta manera la secuencia y me funciona perfecto, espero que te sirva saludos.

```
@Id
@Column(name="WAIVER_OID_NBR")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "waiverOidNbrSq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "waiverOidNbrSq", sequenceName = "WAIVER_DEF_SQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Long waiverOidNbr;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, con MariaDB no funciona, al menos en mi configuración que es la que viene por defecto con XAMPP. Con MySQL funciona sin problemas.